# Processing of GRE subject scores at the institution

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre

I took the physics GRE and at test time sent my scores to my physics department at my school. I later saw my scores and realized that I did very poorly. I am now in the process of applying back to the same school but to a different department which does not require the physics GRE ("Subject test scores are optional but desirable, preferably in Physics...").

If the department looks for my GRE scores, will they get my Physics GRE scores along with my general scores?

The department I am applying to does not have a specific code, just the school code, whereas I sent my score using the physics department code. I am interested in finding out how GRE scores are handled when they are sent from ETS to a school.

Answer (score 1):

Different departments often fetch the GRE scores from the central repository of the Graduate school, would which be fed by official scores from ETS.

So, if the program has declared the GRE score as either mandatory or optional material, the score will be sent there, automatically, from the graduate school.